# make two moving shapes in canvas not overlap (collide) in javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

so i am new to javascript and trying to make kinda like a game... in this game the red ball can move and the blue balls is supposed to follow the red balls like the blue balls should attaracts towards the red one

right now they are following but the blue balls overlaps each other and just turn in 1 ball at last...

i dont want this overlaping... how to stop that?

here's my code

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth-20;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-20;

let gameover = false;
let x = canvas.width / 2;
let y = canvas.height / 2;
let dx = 0;
let dy = 0;

x3=y3=0;
virx = new Array();
viry = new Array();

for (i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    virx.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth-20) + 1));
    viry.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerHeight-20) + 1));
}

const state = {
  "ArrowRight": false,
  "ArrowLeft": false,
  "ArrowUp": false,
  "ArrowDown": false
}



function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();

  for (i=0; i<25; i++)
  {
    newpoint();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(virx[i], viry[i], 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle = "blue";
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
}

function logic() {

  const direction = determineDirection();

  if (direction.dx) {
    dx = dx + direction.dx;
  }

  if (direction.dy) {
    dy = dy + direction.dy;
  }

  x = x + dx;
  y = y + dy;

  if (dx > 0) {
    dx -= 0.02;
  }
  if (dx < 0) {
    dx += 0.02;
  }
  if (dy > 0) {
    dy -= 0.02;
  }
  if (dy < 0) {
    dy += 0.02;
  }

}

function play() {
  draw();
  logic();
}









document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function newpoint()
{
    flag=0;
    vx= x - virx[i];
    vy= y - viry[i];
    vsize = Math.sqrt((vx*vx) + (vy*vy));
    vn_x = vx / vsize;
    vn_y = vy / vsize;

    newx = virx[i] + 0.5 * vn_x;
    newy = viry[i] + 0.5 * vn_y;
    // virx[i] = newx;
    // viry[i] = newy;

    // for (j=0; j<25; j++)
    // {
        // c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((virx[j]-newx), 2)+Math.pow((viry[j]-newy), 2));

        // if (c<20)
        // {
            // flag=1;
        // }
    // }

    if (flag==0)
    {
        virx[i] = newx;
        viry[i] = newy;
    }
}

function determineDirection() {
  const {
    ArrowRight,
    ArrowLeft,
    ArrowUp,
    ArrowDown
  } = state
  if (ArrowRight && ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: .040,
      dy: -.040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowRight && ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: .040,
      dy: .040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft && ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: -.040,
      dy: -.040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft && ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: -.040,
      dy: .040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft) {
    return {
      dx: -.040,
      dy: 0
    }
  }
  if (ArrowRight) {
    return {
      dx: .040,
      dy: 0
    }
  }
  if (ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: 0,
      dy: -.040
    }
  }
  if (ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: 0,
      dy: .040
    }
  }
  return {
    dx: 0,
    dy: 0
  }
}

function keyDownHandler({
  key
}) {
  state[key] = true;
}

function keyUpHandler({
  key
}) {
  state[key] = false;
}
setInterval(play, 10);
```